# Laravel custom validator

Tags: laravel, validation

I have an form where user will post only an email address. I want to validate this input like:

> if that email exists in the table, then a specific column's (e.g.
>    is_valid) data must be null.
>
> if the email doesn't exists then should be validated

I've got solution for the first condition, but can't find anything to combine both.

For first condition my solution:

```
Rule::exists('table_name')->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_valid', null);
});
```

How to write a rule for both conditions?

Comment: I've edited my question, please check now.

Comment: @Rwd I've got solution for the first condition, but can't find anything to combine both.

For first condition my solution -> 
Rule::exists('table_name')->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_valid', null);
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could use something like the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique) rule:

```
Rule::unique('table_name', 'email')->whereNotNull('is_valid');
```

The above should satisfy both conditions you have i.e.

The email doesn't exist at all or it doesn't exist when `is_valid` isn't null.

Comment: not working, your condition in where clause is not correct

Comment: I've used whereNotNull instead of where, now working.

Comment: @MdYeamin Sorry, you're right, a little oversight on my part. I've updated my answer :).